# XML to LINQ with Checking Null Elements

Tags: c#, linq, xml-parsing

The situation I am faced with is parsing an XML document into an object using Linq.  During the parse I am checking to make sure Elements are not null before proceeding to parse out their values.  Is there anyway to simplify this statement?

```
  var variable = (from x in xdoc.Descendants("Root")
                 select new AccountingResponse
                 {      
                 NetCharge = x.Element("Charges") != null && x.Element("Charges").Element("NetCharge") != null ? x.Element("Charges").Element("NetCharge").Value : "0",
                 TotalCharge = x.Element("Charges") != null && x.Element("Charges").Element("TotalCharge") != null ? x.Element("Charges").Element("TotalCharge").Value : "0"
                 }).SingleOrDefault();
```

To summarize, I do not want to continue to check if the nodes exist on each line.  I know I can test to see if the node exists prior to the parsing, but there may be other data that needs parsed to create the AccountingResponse and I want to avoid if statements that only parse a portion of the XML out at a time.

Or perhaps I'm doing this completely wrong and there's a better way!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One simple option is to use `Elements` rather than `Element` - that will return a zero-length sequence if the element isn't present. So you can use:

```
from x in xdoc.Descendants("Root")
select new AccountingResponse
{      
    NetCharge = x.Elements("Charges")
                 .Elements("NetCharge")
                 .Select(y => (int) y)
                 .FirstOrDefault(),
    TotalCharge = x.Elements("Charges")
                   .Elements("TotalCharge")
                   .Select(y => (int) y)
                   .FirstOrDefault(),
}).SingleOrDefault();
```

(Note that your original code wouldn't compile, as `Value` is a string whereas 0 is an int...)

Comment: Why did you do a .Select(x => (int) x)?  Shouldnt it be .Select(y = (int) y.Value)  ??  Since we still need to get at the value of the element and also x is declared above so it needs to be a different variable?

Comment: @cgatian: Yup, had missed the duplicate variable name. Fixing.

Comment: What about .Value instead of just y. Wouldnt that be casting on an XElement? Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @cgatian: That would be trying to cast a `string` to an `int`, which doesn't work. You could use `int.Parse(y.Value)` but I prefer the explicit conversion provided by `XElement`.

Answer (score 3):

In C# 6.0 you can use monadic Null-conditional operator `?.` 
After applying it in your example it would look like this:

```
var variable = (from x in xdoc.Descendants("Root")
                select new
                {
                    NetCharge = x.Element("Charges")?.Element("NetCharge")?.Value ?? "0",
                    TotalCharge = x.Element("Charges")?.Element("TotalCharge")?.Value ?? "0"
                }).SingleOrDefault();
```

You can read more [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6) in part titled Null-conditional operators.

Comment: This is nice.  It helped me reduce a clunky multi-line helper method to just one line: `return orgElem.Element("subs")?.Elements("organization") ?? Enumerable.Empty<XElement>();`

Answer (score 2):

You can replace

```
x.Element("nodeName") != null : int.Parse(x.Element("nodeName").Value) : 0
```

with

```
(int)x.Element("nodeName")
```

It works for `string`, `int`, `double`, `decimal`, `bool`, `uint`, `DateTime` and `Nullable` of those as well.

Comment: I'm not seeing any call to `int.Parse` in the original code... which admittedly wouldn't compile.

Comment: I don't think the original code compiles at all, that's why I added `int.Parse()`