# Linq to XML Element inside Element

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I wrote a method to read XML and write information to an object. The XML contains elements with the information, but some of the information is encapsulated and I can't figure out how to get to the information out of it. The XML contains about 200 "results".

**XML structure**

```
 <result id="xxxxx">
      <name>Name</name>
      <age>25</age>
      <info>
           <x>Some text</x>
           <y>More Text</y>
      </info>
 </result>
```

**Code**

```
XDocument rootDocument = XDocument.Load(file);
var xy = from r in rootDocument.Descendants("result")
        select new
        {
            Name = r.Element("name")
            Age = r.Element("age"),
            x = r.Element("info").Element("x"),
            y = r.Element("info").Element("y"),
        };

foreach (var r in xy)
{
    Object o = new Object()
    {
        Name = r.Name,
        Age = r.Age,
        x = r.x,
        y = r.y
    };
}
```

**Error**
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The Error occurs at the line

```
  x = r.Element("info")...
```

and the following one.

Comment: Is there an error or warning you're getting? I don't see the problem (other than wrong syntax for the line `Object o = new Object();`).

Comment: Yes, it was edited. I don't know why. I'll add it again.

Comment: Is there any XML node where `info` does not have `x` and `y` values?

Comment: It is always the same. X and Y nodes can be empty, but not nonexistend.

Comment: Check out [Jon's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15837895/6741868). It describes a safe null checking method. Basically something like `x = r.Element("info") != null ? r.Element("info").Element("x"), : null` could also work.

Comment: Are you sure the root XML node or some other parent node of `<result>` doesn't have a default namespace -- an `xmlns="some namespace"` attribute?  We could answer your question more definitely if you share a [mcve] that includes the actual XML that causes the exception to be thrown.

Comment: It appears that some of the result tags do not have a child info.  Simplest solution is to use descendants which will return null instead of error : x = r.Descendants("x").FirstOrDefault(),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
var query = from r in rootDocument.Descendants("result")
            select new
            {
                Name = (string)r.Element("name"),
                Age = (int?)r.Element("age"),
                x = (string)r.Elements("info").Elements("x").SingleOrDefault(),
                y = (string)r.Elements("info").Elements("x").SingleOrDefault(),
            };
var resultList = query.ToList();
```

Notes:

- Once you have selected an `XElement` with a primitive value, you can convert the element to a c# primitive such as `string` or `int?` by using one of `XElement`'s [explicit casting operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx#Operators), like so:

  ```
  Name = (string)r.Element("name")
  Age = (int?)r.Element("age")
  ```
- The fact that you are seeing an *Object reference not set to an instance of an object* exception suggests that an element is unexpectedly missing.  That could easily happen if one of the `<result>` elements were missing an `<info>` child element.  The expression

  ```
  r.Elements("info").Elements("x")
  ```

  returns **all** child elements named `<x>` of child element(s) named `<info>`.  Then [`SingleOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the only element of that sequence, or a default value if the sequence is empty.  This protects against the situation when an `<info>` is missing.
- Similarly, if the `<age>` element is missing, trying to cast it to `int` would throw a null reference exception since `int` is a value type.  Casting to `int?` instead returns null instead of throwing the exception.
- The final [`ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) evaluates the query and returns the results in a list.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uROkd8).

Comment: Perfectly explained and sampled. Thank you!